# What is the best way to export specific pages from multiple PDF files?

Tags: pdf, export

I have a bunch of PDF files to go through but from most of those files I only need 1 or 2 pages. So for instance: From PDF 1 I need page 3, from PDF 2 I need page 5, etc.

I want to export those pages to separate PDF files.

If you have a suggestion to speed up this process that would be great!

Comment: What OS and what PDF software do you have?  pdftk (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and imagemagick (http://www.imagemagick.org) are two options.

Comment: I normally just use Adobe Acrobat or similar program. If I needed to extract certain page from multiple PDF documents, I would merge them into a single document, then extract the pages at that point

Comment: cxw: I'm running Windows 8.1 and I only have the default adobe software. I'll try out your options, thank you.

Comment: Ramhound: That's pretty clever actually. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a [free online tool](http://www.splitpdf.com/) you can use which will allow you to split a single PDF into multiple PDF documents.

Example:

I have a PDF with pages 1,2,3 & 4. 
I only want pages 1 & 4.

This tool will allow you to do this.

This [other free online tool](http://smallpdf.com/merge-pdf) will allow you to split, merge, compress and convert PDF's - might be useful too!